# How to use statsmodels' DynamicFactor method with exogenous variables?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, multivariate-time-series

I have a multivariate dynamic factor model with one common factor that I want to estimate with statsmodels.tsa.statespace.dynamic_factor.DynamicFactor.

The model looks as follows:
[Model formulation in LaTeX.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiMaV.png)*

As you can see, I am dealing with a t x 4 matrix of endogenous variables. Each of them has 6 own specific exogenous variables, which they don't share. So the only thing the 4 time series have in common, is the common factor.

My question is how to put this in code.

I have attempted the following:

```
model = DynamicFactor(
                        endog=y, # nobs x 4
                        exog=X, # nobs x k_exog
                        k_factors=1,
                        factor_order=1,
                        error_order=0,
                        error_cov_type='diagonal'
    )
```

But the results seem off, and I know from the documentation that X should have the shape of t x k_exog. I am wondering what k_exog should be in my case, and if I can arange my matrix so that y_1 only uses W_1 etc.

*EDIT: in the model formulation, at one point the dependent variable is called 'NG' but it should be y. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DynamicFactor` model assumes that every `exog` variable affects every `endog` variable. However, you can tell the model to set the values of certain parameters to fixed values (rather than estimate them). You can use this to do what you want.

A simple example follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Simulate some data
nobs = 100
np.random.seed(1234)
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(nobs, 2)), columns=['y1', 'y2'])
X_1 = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=nobs), name='x1')
X_2 = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=nobs), name='x2')
X = pd.concat([X_1, X_2], axis=1)

# Construct the model
mod = sm.tsa.DynamicFactor(y, exog=X, k_factors=1, factor_order=1)

# You can print the parameter names if you need to determine the
# names of the parameters that you need to set fixed to 0
# print(mod.param_names)

# Fix the applicable parameters with `fix_params`...
with mod.fix_params({'beta.x2.y1': 0, 'beta.x1.y2': 0}):
    # And  estimate the other parameters with `fit`
    res = mod.fit(disp=False)

# Print the results
print(res.summary())
```

Which gives:

```
                                   Statespace Model Results                                  
=============================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                          ['y1', 'y2']   No. Observations:                  100
Model:             DynamicFactor(factors=1, order=1)   Log Likelihood                -276.575
                                      + 2 regressors   AIC                            567.150
Date:                               Fri, 12 May 2023   BIC                            585.386
Time:                                       22:45:16   HQIC                           574.530
Sample:                                            0                                         
                                               - 100                                         
Covariance Type:                                 opg                                         
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):             0.01, 0.10   Jarque-Bera (JB):           5.22, 0.78
Prob(Q):                        0.93, 0.76   Prob(JB):                   0.07, 0.68
Heteroskedasticity (H):         2.11, 0.75   Skew:                     -0.56, -0.17
Prob(H) (two-sided):            0.04, 0.41   Kurtosis:                   3.02, 3.26
                           Results for equation y1                            
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
loading.f1    -0.4278      0.891     -0.480      0.631      -2.174       1.318
beta.x1       -0.0614      0.129     -0.478      0.633      -0.313       0.191
beta.x2             0        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
                           Results for equation y2                            
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
loading.f1     0.4487      0.888      0.505      0.613      -1.292       2.189
beta.x1             0        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
beta.x2       -0.1626      0.113     -1.442      0.149      -0.384       0.058
                        Results for factor equation f1                        
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
L1.f1          0.1060      0.323      0.328      0.743      -0.527       0.739
                           Error covariance matrix                            
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sigma2.y1      0.6124      0.766      0.800      0.424      -0.889       2.113
sigma2.y2      0.9306      0.818      1.138      0.255      -0.672       2.533
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
```